# Method that returns result and modulo

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a method that asks for two 2 integers, and divides the first by the second and returns the result including the remainder.

```
def remainder(a,b)
  return a/b
  return a%b
end
puts remainder(100,6)
```

This puts out

```
16
```

If I use this code

```
def remainder(a,b)
  return a%b
end
puts remainder(100,6)
```

This puts out

```
4
```

I don't understand how to make both the modulus value and the remainder show in puts statement.

***Update***
Based on Simple Lime's advice I used the following code...

```
def remainder(a,b)
  return a.divmod(b)
end
puts remainder(100,6)
```

Which puts

```
16
4
```

And is functioning as I had hoped.

Comment: Once you return, you exit the function. You can't return twice. You'll need to group the two values together into some kind of object, like a tuple, then return that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an array from the method when you need to return multiple values:

```
def remainder(a, b)
  [a / b, a % b]
end

puts remainder(100, 6).inspect # => [16, 4]
```

and then you can assign each value to a different variable, if you need:

```
div, mod = remainder(100, 6)
puts div # => 16
puts mod # => 4
```

---

As a side note, if you are just needing both the quotient and modulus of 2 numbers, there's already a built-in function, [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) that does this, using the technique above:

```
100.divmod(6) # => [16, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the last way you showed. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: I suggest you change your penultimate line to something like, "It would be simpler, however, to use Ruby's built-in method [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) for that:". Maybe others would read it differently, but I wasn't sure you were implying that `divmod` should be used or it was just an alternative solution.

Comment: Ah, yeah just an alternative option, I couldn't tell from the question if this was like a "learning to do stuff" type of question or a "they actually needed a function to do this and chose to write it from scratch not knowing about the built-in one"

Comment: Took another stab at the wording in the question, to separate it into what they were asking, and what they may have been wanting